# How to convert Java code to smali - dalvik bytcode

Tags: java, android

I have java codes (android studio) how can I convert it to .smali?

Example: java

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        a(this.a.a());
    }
```

---

.smali (dalvik code)

```
.method public onStart()V
    .locals 1

    .line 80
    invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/support/v7/app/e;->onStart()V

    .line 82
    iget-object v0, p0, Llkstudio/uchannel/ManHinhDangNhapActivity;->a:Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth;->a()Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser;

    move-result-object v0

    .line 83
    invoke-direct {p0, v0}, Llkstudio/uchannel/ManHinhDangNhapActivity;->a(Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser;)V

    return-void
.end method
```

Comment: Instead just asking why, you may give what have you done so far and which part you are stack, will make people to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [ApkTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) which decompile the APK, means that extract the smali files.

Example:

`java -jar apktool.jar d -f MyApp.apk -o MyApp_Decompiled/`

`ls -lha MyApp_Decompiled/`

> -rw-r--r--   1 wolf users  12K Mar 26 21:16 AndroidManifest.xml
>
> drwxr-xr-x 143 wolf users 4.0K Mar 26 21:16 res
>
> drwxr-xr-x  13 wolf users 4.0K Mar 26 21:16 smali
>
> drwxr-xr-x   8 wolf users 4.0K Mar 26 21:16 smali_classes2
>
> drwxr-xr-x   4 wolf users 4.0K Mar 26 21:16 smali_classes3

`ls -lha MyApp_Decompiled/smali/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/`

> -rw-r--r-- 1 wolf users 4.8K Mar 26 21:16  AirMapCalloutManager.smali
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 wolf users  956 Mar 26 21:16  AirMapCallout.smali
>
> -rw-r--r-- 1 wolf users 6.5K Mar 26 21:16  AirMapCircleManager.smali

---

If you only want to convert one file, I recommend to use this Jar tool.

[Techno-Developer / Java2Smali](https://github.com/Techno-Developer/Java2Smali)

`java -jar Java2Smali.jar <JavaSourceFile>`

---

If you want to see more options try it:

[Git Hub Java2Smali search.](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=java2smali&s=updated&type=Repositories)

[Extended search for Java and Smali.](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=java%20smali&s=updated&type=Repositories)